# Brace Expansion and Readline

Tags: bash, readline

If I have the following:

```
a=xyz
echo $a
```

I can execute the readline command C-M-e after the `$a` and get:

```
echo xyz
```

before the command is executed.

However, if I type:

```
echo a{x,y,z}b
```

and then issue the readline command C-M-e, I still get:

```
echo a{x,y,z}b
```

not as I was expecting:

```
echo axb ayb azb
```

Is there a readline command for brace expansion?

Answer (score 2):

As of bash 4.2, there is no way to perform brace expansion on the command line input.

Answer (score 2):

bash doesn't support it, you could work around it with a sub-shell:

```
echo `echo a{x,y,z}b`
```

brace expansion is supported by zsh by the way.